# AngularJS: Merge object by ID, i.e. replace old entry when IDs are identical

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic with AngularJS and I am using a localForage database and AJAX via $http. My app has a news stream that contains data like this:

```
{ 
    "feed":[  
        {  
             "id":"3",
             "title":"Ein Hund",
             "comments:"1"
         },
         {  
             "id":"2",
             "title":"Eine Katze",
             "comments":"2"
          }
       ],
   "ts":"20150907171943"
}
```

`ts` stands for Timestamp. My app saves the feed locally via localForage.

When the app starts it first loads the locally saved items:

```
$localForage.getItem("feed").then(function(val) { vm.feed = val; })
```

Then, it loads the new or updated items (`ts < current timestamp`) and merges both the old and new data:

```
angular.extend(vm.feed, response.data.feed);
```

Updated items look like this:

```
{  
   "feed":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "title":"Eine Katze",
         "comments":"4"
      }
   ],
   "ts":"20150907171944"
}
```

That is, the comments count on feed item 2 has changed from 2 to 4. When I merge the old and new data, `vm.feed` has two items with id = 2.

Does angularjs has a built-in "merge by id" function, i. e. copy from source to destination (if it is a new element), or otherwise replace the old element? In case angularjs does not have such a function, what's the best way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: merge implies there are some properties of the original item you want to maintain, but from reading your description, I'm not sure this is the case. Completely replacing the old item with the new one is easier but it will be manual. Foreach item that is returned, determine if it is already in the collection. If yes, replace it. If no, add it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.merge(vm.feed, response.data.feed);`

// EDIT

Probably, it will not merge correctly, so you  have to update all properties manually. Update `ts` property and then find your object with `id` and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin, I usually write my own merge function:

```
(function(){

  function itemsToArray(items) {
    var result = [];
    if (items) {
      // items can be a Map, so don't use angular.forEach here
      items.forEach(function(item) {
        result.push(item);
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

  function idOf(obj) {
    return obj.id;
  }

  function defaultMerge(newItem, oldItem) {
    return angular.merge(oldItem, newItem);
  }

  function mergeById(oldItems, newItems, idSelector, mergeItem) {
    if (mergeItem === undefined) mergeItem = defaultMerge;
    if (idSelector === undefined) idSelector = idOf;
    // Map retains insertion order
    var mapping = new Map();
    angular.forEach(oldItems, function(oldItem) {
      var key = idSelector(oldItem);
      mapping.set(key, oldItem);
    });
    angular.forEach(newItems, function(newItem) {
      var key = idSelector(newItem);
      if (mapping.has(key)) {
        var oldItem = mapping.get(key);
        mapping.set(key, mergeItem(newItem, oldItem));
      } else {
        // new items are simply added, will be at
        // the end of the result list, in order
        mapping.set(key, newItem);
      }
    });
    return itemsToArray(mapping);
  }


  var olds = [
    { id: 1, name: 'old1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'old2' }
  ];
  var news = [
    { id: 3, name: 'new3' },
    { id: 2, name: 'new2' }
  ];

  var merged = mergeById(olds, news);
  console.log(merged);
  /* Prints
  [
    { id: 1, name: 'old1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'new2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'new3' }
  ];
  */
})();
```

This builds a `Map` from the old items by id, merges in the new items, and converts the map back to list. Fortunately the `Map` object will iterate on the entries in insertion order, according to the specification. You can provide your `idSelector` and `mergeItem` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hege_hegedus. Based on your code, I've written my own and tried to use less loops to speed things up a bit:

```
function updateCollection(localCollection, fetchedCollection)  {
    angular.forEach(fetchedCollection, function(item) {
        var append = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < localCollection.length; i++) {
            if (localCollection[i].id == item.id) {
                // Replace item
                localCollection[i] = item;
                append = false;
                break;
            } else if (localCollection[i].id > item.id) {
                // Add new element at the right position, if IDs are descending check for "< item.id" instead
                localCollection.splice(i, 0, item);
                append = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (append) {
            // Add new element with a higher ID at the end
            localCollection.push(item);
            // When IDs are descending use .unshift(item) instead
        }
    });
}
```

There is still room for improvements, i. e. the iteration through all the objects should use binary search since all items are sorted by id.